# Import Oracle to HDFS by Sqoop with 3 records is OK. Failed for full table

Tags: oracle, hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

I import data from Oracle to HDFS by Sqoop with 3 record is OK with this command:

```
./sqoop-import --connect <oracle-jdbc-string> --username <my-user-name> --password <my-password> --table SYS_GROUP --where "Sys_Group_ID < 4"
```

The job completed succesfully with 3 records.

But when I want to import full table, it failed.
Command:

```
./sqoop-import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.58.71.164:1521:dbmss01 --username <my-user-name> --password <my-password> --table SYS_GROUP --fetch-size 100
```

Log:

```
15/12/04 02:32:19 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1448967962138_0005 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1448967962138_0005_m_000003<br><br>
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0
15/12/04 02:32:19 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred 378.3994 KB in 96.9962 seconds (3.9012 KB/sec)<br><br>
15/12/04 02:32:19 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 1474 records.<br><br>
15/12/04 02:32:19 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Error during import: Import job failed!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try increasing the number of mappers by appending --m 5 at the end

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at wrong logs, you need to look at map task logs. Go to resource manager web UI, navigate to map reduce job, click on failed map task and see what the issue is.

Comment: Very last lines of the logs: 2015-12-04 11:43:57,176 INFO [Thread-84] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.JobHistoryEventHandler: In stop, writing event MAP_ATTEMPT_KILLED

Comment: Can you paste the complete log?

Comment: It seems memory problem. Because I imported 800 rows is OK, but full table (1702 rows) is failed :(

Comment: try increasing the number of mappers by appending **-m 5** at the end

Comment: @yoga: You saved my life. It works like a charm. But it is --m, not -m, lol. What is the best value for --m? Does it depend on server's CPU, RAM???

Comment: @phucdull: It depends on size of the table, index on the column, capacity of the underlying database to determine right number of mappers. At time abnormally high configuration of number of mappers can cause serious impact on the source database.

Comment: @DurgaViswanathGadiraju: Thanks sir, copied your advice in notepad to keep this deeply in mind :D

Comment: The import command makes lot of files in target, such as part-m-000*. What can I do to make it into a single file to execute Spark jobs on this?

Comment: Number of files will be equal to number of mappers. There will not be any issue with spark. You can pass the path of directory.

Comment: @phucdull glad it worked.the value of mappers depends on data size you aare importing and how fast you want to import.